# handle Powerpoint shape click event in c# code

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I want to handle a powerpoint shape's click event in slide show mode.
I want to write event handler in a C# vsto addin.
Please help me I am stuck in this as in google search I am not able to find any answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal view, you could respond to the Selection Changed event to determine whether a particular shape had been clicked, but you can't select anything in slide show view.

But you can assign an action setting to a shape, make it a Run Macro action and have it call a bit of VBA code within the presentation, for example:

```
Sub AndThenHeClickedMe(oSh as Shape)
  MsgBox "You clicked " & oSh.Name
End Sub
```

Your VBA code could possibly call a DLL that you provide as well, so you don't need to write all of the following code in VBA if you don't wish to.

Comment: Hi Steve Thanku for your answer but i don't have option to write anything in vba

Comment: One other thought:  PowerPoint has PointsToScreenPixelsX and PointsToScreenPixelsY methods. You could possibly iterate through the shapes on a given slide until you locate a shape that's under the current cursor position within the current window.  No idea, really, whether it can be made to work, but it's the only other approach I can think of.